# Install package "MareyMap" in R or RStudio on Mac. "Installation of package had non-zero exit status"

Tags: r, macos, installation, package

I am not able to install the R package "MareyMap" in neither in R nor RStudio on my Macbook Pro 10.10.5 OS X Yosemite

This package requires the pre installation of packages "trkplot" and "tcltk", which I installed succesfully. I also tried installing it after installing R through homebrew, without success.

Every time I tried to install "MareyMap" after the R prompt, I get this:

```
Warning message:
In install.packages("MareyMap") :
  installation of package ‘MareyMap’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please help !

Comment: This looks like a bug with the MareyMap package. You should try to contact the developer with a bug report http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/software/mareymap/development.php

Comment: OK thank you @TennysonH

Answer (score 1):

I am not very homebrew or Macs but you may wanna make sure you have the latest version of R. The MareyMap package was just developed in August of 2015 so if you have you have an old version of R perhaps upgrading to 3.2.2 or 3.2.3 might help? I was able to install it with 3.2.2 but not on my other computer which had 3.1.1

Comment: Thank you @user53559. I have 3.2.3